# What about these stylized tags like SO has?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Over in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) there are some tags that have little icons in them ([Android], various Adobe related tags, etc.) which are both annoying (why should Adobe get extra advertising for free?) and nice (easy to understand quickly what the tag is about).

I think we should have a little discussion about some of our tags being augmented with graphics. I can think of a few: [latex] (the typeset \latex ofcourse), [mathmode] (a $-sign?, or a formula e^{i \pi}?) [symbols] (one of the crazy math symbols), [debugging] (a little red ladybug?)

anyhow, maybe this is too early, silly, not important...that's why I'm asking what people think!

Comment: And btw, the use of the [latex] tag is [discouraged](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302/our-set-of-tags).

Answer (score 13):

I don't think anyone gets advertising for free. As far as I know, these decorated tags are *because* Adobe paid for it. I also think they're ugly as hell, and unless it's an important source of income, I'd rather avoid them....

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, those tags are sponsored. I like them, though.

Comment: I like them too, but _only_ when the icon on the tag actually represents the tag. Unless they can be restricted in that manner, I vote against having them at all.

Comment: So unless e.g. the AMS wants to pay for them ...

Answer (score 5):

They're the opposite of free; they're *because* a company paid to [sponsor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean) them